# Fetch POST method gives empty body on Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I make a POST request from my browser client:

```
const post = async (url, body) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: `POST`,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body
            });
            return response.json();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
        }
    }
const data = await post(`http://localhost:4050/analyze`, { text });
```

And I handle it on Express server with this setup:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This is my route:

```
router.post(`/`, errorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { text } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)

    const value = await analyze(text);

    res.json({ rephrased });
}));
```

The console.log shows me this:

```
{ 'object Object': '' }
```

Why fetch method gives me Object instead of text property?

UPDATE:
When I do Stringify:

```
        method: `POST`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
```

The body became like this and console.log shows:

```
{ '{"text":"asdfasdf"}': '' }
```

Comment: What do you see in the network monitor? I guess the frontend sends `object Object`. You have to serialize `body`.

Comment: @jabaa check my Update with Stringify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `fetch` a plain object for the `body` and it doesn't know what to do with it, so it calls `.toString()` and gives you nothing useful.

Pass it a `URLSearchParams` object instead. (Here I assume `text` is a string)

```
const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.append("text", text);
```

This will convert to a application/x-www-form-urlencoded string.

(You can also omit the `headers` as `fetch` can infer the correct `Content-Type` from the `URLSearchParams` object.)

---

Re edit: `JSON.stringify` will encode the data as JSON. JSON is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded.